# What is the etymology behind the name Vichitravirya?

Tags: mahabharata

In Mahabharatha, mostly all names have a reason/etymology behind them. One that I couldnt find was "Vichitravirya"- Son of Shantanu and father of Dhritrashtra & Pandu. Name clearly transliterates to "Weird Sperm".

Comment: Sperm means  virya , but in sanskrit virya means shaktiman (powerful man) , virya means Power

Comment: Vichitra virya was not powerful at all. He was not even half a solider. He was not a healthy son right from his childhood.

Comment: your name is mohit , you have any quality(guna) of your name ?

Comment: Yes, but why do you need to get personal on that note? Make your point.
If you are trying to say that its not necessary person would have guna of his name, then you are mistaken. Naming in our epics doesnt work that way

Comment: point is "jese name hote hai eeese gun nahi hote " nothing personal bro

Comment: Thats not how it worked in epics writing Bhavin. I can give you over 100 examples of how names in Mahabharata times gave a direct summary of their deeds or nature.

Comment: yes right like Bheesma after Bheesm Pratigya , before his name was Devvrat , but i can not find why his name was devvrat , but some times it's true that  "jese name hote hai eeese gun nahi hote "

Comment: Devvrat means someone who has divine looks, intelligence and bravery. This was so called "niyati" for son of Divine king Shantanu and Godess Ganga, as predicted by Gods. Thats why the name Devvrat.